# Error : expected specifier qualifier list before FILE in header struct

Tags: c, struct

Hi im getting a couple of compiler warnings in and i cant figure out the problem. I have solved other little issues but this ones just bugging me.
Thank you for your help

Mark

**agent.h:10: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘FILE’**

```
#ifndef AGENT_H
#define AGENT_H
struct AgentInfo {
      int cordRow;
      int cordCol;
      char indicator;
      char* fileName;
      char direction;
      pid_t agentPid;
      FILE* agentIn;//Error shows here
      FILE* agentOut;;
      struct AgentInfo *next;

}; 
struct AgentInfo *createLinkedList(int r,int c, char i, char *fn, char dir);
struct AgentInfo *addToLinkedList(int r,int c, char i, char *fn, char dir);
struct AgentInfo *findAgent(char* fn, struct AgentInfo **prevAgent);
extern struct AgentInfo *head = NULL;
extern struct AgentInfo *current = NULL;
#endif
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `FILE` is not a primitive type; it is contained in the `stdio.h` header. So you need to include it using `#include <stdio.h>` within your file.

Comment: oh no now im getting a Undefined symbols for architecture with "_decode_start_pos", referenced from: \n _main in ccS7sGqg.o \n
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -c error.c -o error.o\n
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -c agent.c -o agent.o\n
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -c io.c -o io.o\n
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic -c map.c -o map.o\n
and i compile with \n
gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -pedantic handler.c -o handler\n
any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry @MarkNicolle, I can't help you without having more details. I believe you would have to open another question if you can't figure it out with research.

Comment: Ok i've just posted another question. Cheers @nims